# What is wrong with my HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, bad-sectors

[image: HDD]

The first value marked in  yellow is seen in the picture and the other is:
**Current pending Sector Count Current:100 Worst:100 Threshold:0 Raw Values:000000000003**
Whatever this problem  is, is making my PC freeze. Is there any way to solve this?
What is wrong with my HDD?

Comment: It means that the drive is detecting bad sectors and reallocating them to "spare" sectors on the drive.  A few such sectors is fairly normal, but if you start getting more and more the drive is dying and should be replaced (or at least backed up) ASAP.

Comment: Why does it cause my computer to freeze??

Comment: When it encounters a bad sector it spends time trying to read it, playing tricks such as moving the read/write head slightly to one side or the other, reading several times and trying to take the "average" of the data, etc.  This all takes time.

Comment: @DanielRHicks So lets assume that it is about to fail and I have to buy a new one, I  will lose my genuine OS. Is there anyway to back that up?

Comment: Just boot up and copy your product key down, then back up files that you can. You'd probably be better off backing up from a LiveCD if your Os keeps crashing.

Comment: @ekaj the product ID that I get in the System Properties is what you are talking about?

Comment: Go to start, right click computer, click properties, the product key for the OS will be at the bottom of that page.

Comment: @ekaj  The raw values are very low but still the computer freezes. Will defragmentation help?

Comment: @ekaj product key never  show up there he can use a third party tool for that.

Comment: @avirk guide me!

Comment: It could be any process which cause the system to freeze. Better to check out through the process monitor or task manager. Also run a memory test.

Comment: @avirk move it to chat!

Comment: [Here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/productkeysactivation/tp/topkeyfinder.htm) you will see many free key finders.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/5865/discussion-between-fasih-khatib-and-avirk)

Comment: @DanielRHicks : Post that as an answer please.

Comment: @Shiki: I had to buy a new one. It was dying.

Answer (score 0):

Every drive comes with a "reserve". If there is a bad sector, the drive tries to re-allocate that sector. Basically it tries to save the drive.

While this seem like a solution, it's just a dirty workaround.
Once this happens, you should always get a new replacement.

From the [SMART Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) article:

> Count of reallocated sectors. When the hard drive finds a
>   read/write/verification error, it marks that sector as "reallocated"
>   and transfers data to a special reserved area (spare area). This
>   process is also known as remapping, and reallocated sectors are called
>   "remaps". The raw value normally represents a count of the bad sectors
>   that have been found and remapped. Thus, the higher the attribute
>   value, the more sectors the drive has had to reallocate. This allows a
>   drive with bad sectors to continue operation; however, a drive which
>   has had any reallocations at all is significantly more likely to fail
>   in the near future.[2] While primarily used as a metric of the life
>   expectancy of the drive, this number also affects performance. As the
>   count of reallocated sectors increases, the read/write speed tends to
>   become worse because the drive head is forced to seek to the reserved
>   area whenever a remap is accessed. A workaround which will preserve
>   drive speed at the expense of capacity is to create a disk partition
>   over the region which contains remaps and instruct the operating
>   system to not use that partition.