# Final questions regarding installing a new system HDD

Tags: backup, partitioning, operating-systems, hp-pavilion

Of late, my HDD has started to fail and I have to buy a new one. Being a total noob I encountered the following issues:

- Backing up the data.
  I solved this problem by using DIXML (Thanks to the SE Community)
- Reinstalling my genuine Win7 Home Premium back into new HDD.
  I was told that I could do this using the recovery disks that I have created but I am still unsure of that. My OS is pre-installed with my laptop.
- Creating Recovery Partition and HP_Tools Partition
  I dont know how to do this and HP's help forum was of no significant help.

Please help me with saving my genuine OS and creating Recovery and HP_Tools partition. How do I do that?

HP Pavilion DV4-2126TX

Comment: Please add the make/model of your PC/laptop. The diagnostics (HP System Diagnostics UEFI) can be downloaded and installed after you have reinstalled windows and it creates the partition during install.

Comment: HP Pavilion DV4-2126TX

Comment: I've edited your question title to remove "buying", people here can get twitchy about that.

Comment: I believe if you reinstall windows using the HP recovery media, it will recreate the HP recovery and tools partitions. I'm not 100% on this though.

Comment: How do  I know which HDD is  compatible with my  laptop? I currently have [this](http://superuser.com/questions/476849/what-is-wrong-with-my-hdd) . You can see the name in the Image. ST######

Comment: That is a Seagate - Momentus 7200rpm ST9320423AS, 320 GB, internal - 2.5 hard drive. They are still available but any equivalent hard drive will do.